# MS Excel: Add the contents of the column A to the cell B, if column B is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

how can I add the contents of the cell A to the cell B, if cell B is empty in MS Excel 2010?

### My situation in detail:

- Column A (column with some empty and some non-empty values): AD
- Column B (no empty values here): I

Now I need Excel to fill the column AD with the values from the column I, if a value in the column AD is missing. Otherwise the original value from the column AD should remain.

Note: All columns contain text data (no numbers, currency etc.)

### My approach:

=IF((AD3)="";I3;AD3)

But this doesn't work as expected: it just throws a circular reference error and fills the column AD3 with "0" in spite of any other values.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a circular reference because the cell only holds one piece of information. Currently, using row 3 as an example, AD3 contains a value (lets say "Hello"). As soon as you try and put a function in, AD3 now contains the function and "Hello" is completely gone. Now it'll keep trying to pull up the function referencing AD3 infinitely.

You'd be better off using a helper column for this if you want to use a formula, otherwise you'll need to hard code it. Personally, I'd add a new column AE, hide the column AD, and use the formula you've used in AE.

Other options you have are to run a VBA macro across it, something like this:

```
Sub FillBlanksFromI()
    Dim j
    For j = 1 To FindLastRow("AD")
        If IsEmpty(Range("AD" & j).Value) Then
            Range("AD" & j).Value = Range("I" & j).Value
        End If
    Next j
End Sub

Function FindLastRow(col As String) As Long

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    FindLastRow = lastRow

End Function
```

... which will go through an fill any blank fields with their value from I. This ***WILL NOT*** automatically update, and would only work once.

Alternatively, you need to hard code each function in each cell to either be the value, or `=I3`

Comment: Thank you very much, using a helper column did the trick. I created a new column AE3 and modified the formula as follows: =IF((AE3)="";I3;AD3) and now it aggregates values from both columns AD3 and I3 - just fine for me for the moment.